# how to remove the lines between data points

Tags: python, matplotlib

I use the following script to plot a graph.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Sample data
model_a_flops = [1e9, 1.7e9, 2.8e9, 3.53e9, 4.1e9]  
model_b_flops = [0.8e9, 1.4e9, 2.2e9, 2.94e9, 3.8e9] 
model_c_flops = [0.2e9, 1.3e9, 1.8e9, 2.85e9, 3.1e9] 
gflops = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500]  # Example sequence lengths

# Creating the line graph
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 4))
plt.plot(model_a_flops, gflops, label='Model A', marker='o')
plt.plot(model_b_flops, gflops, label='Model B', marker='^')
plt.plot(model_c_flops, gflops, label='Model C', marker='s')

# Adding titles and labels
plt.xlabel('G')
plt.ylabel('A')
plt.legend()
plt.grid(True)
plt.tight_layout()

# Show the plot
plt.show()
```

The output is as follows[image]:

How can I remove the lines between all the data points? I mean, I only want to show the data points for each model, but I do not want to connect them.

Comment: Change `plt.plot()` to `plt.scatter()`?  Or `plt.plot(..., linestyle='')`